# How to get the above equation for semi group of Markov chain?

Tags: probability, analysis

if we have a continuous time ergodic Markov process with generator $A$,  Markov semi-group $(P_t)_{t>0}=e^{tA}$ and stationary distribution $\mu$. Assume this Markov chain is $\mu$-ergodic, that means
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty} P_t f(x)=\mu(f):=\int f \mu
$$
in $L^2$ for smooth functions $f$.

Then we can write
$$
f(x)-\int fd\mu=-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{d}{dt}E[f(X_t)|X_0=x]dt
$$

How to get the above one?

---

I know the definition of generator that is

$$
\mathcal{A}f(x)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\mathcal{A}_tf(x)-f(x)}{t}
$$
where $\mathcal{A}_tf(x)=E[f(X_t)|X_0=x]$.

It seems that
$$
-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{d}{dt}E[f(X_t)|X_0=x]dt=-\int_0^{\infty} d(E[f(X_t)|X_0=x])=?
$$

Comment: In your first equation, you have $f$ without an argument. What is that supposed to be?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth We can assume that $f$ is smooth and bounded.

Comment: That's not what I mean. When you say $f(x)-\mu f$, what is $f$ in the last term?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth That is $\int f d\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the Markov Process in question is $X_t$. $\mathcal{A}$ being the Markov generator of $X_t$, we can write for $f\in D_\mathcal{A}$
$$d/dt (P_t f(x)) = \mathcal{A} P_t f(x) $$
Which allows us to write
$$P_t f(x) = P_0 f(x) + \int_0^t \mathcal{A} P_t f(x)dt $$
knowing $P_0 = Id$ and $P_t f(x)= \mathbb{E}[f(X_t)|X_0=x]$
$$ f(x) - P_t f(x) = - \int_0^t \mathcal{A} P_t f(x) = -\int_0^t \frac{d}{dt}E[f(X_t)|X_0=x]dt $$
The desired result follows from taking $t \rightarrow \infty$.